# About charging Li-ion batteries in mobile devices

Tags: battery-charging, charging, mobile

I've got some questions about charging Li-ion batteries in mobile devices.

1. Does mobile phones that are made by major manufacturers like Samsung have solutions for charging safety in their devices? If there is, how does it work?
2. What happens if charging voltage or current exceeds the levels of the charging battery? Can the safety solutions prevent all the unexpected damages? For example, battery designed to be charged at 9V/1.67A is charged by 12V/5A or suddenly gets shorted.
3. Is there any situations happening during the charge that can cause li-ion battery to explode? Like electrical shorts or sth...?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: These are not design questions but use of a consumer product and are therefore off topic for this site. However, you should find answers at http://batteryuniversity.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are Lithium Ion, the company would be insane to not provide a decent safety. If the current or input voltage exceeds the packs max, nothing will happen because its regulated by the systems PMIC, which will output a charging voltage and current that is safe for use with the corresponding battery. Mobile phones are charged over USB which is a 5V 1 A system, it will never get near 9 or twelve volts, if it did the phone would get rather unhappy...  but this question is off topic. Its not a design question, go dig out a schematic for a phone and look at its power supply, and the charging circuitry. That will teach you more, but I am also sure you can find tons on google!

the last question in your question.

I race model touring cars, my packs come off the track hot, and get charged straight after, while still in most cases, hot, packs that aren't designed for this kind of use are likely to explode, so as long as the pack is used as its designed, it wont explode, a few things that could cause it to vent or explode.

shorting.

over charging.

under charging.

drawing to much, or using a undersized battery for your intended application.

puncturing the cell.

Dodgy electronics.

Comment: Mobile phones are NOT charged from 5V 1A only. Nearly all phones will accept more. Some 5V with up to 1,5 A, some up to 9 V with up to 1,67A or 5V and up to 2A. Battery does NOT directly consume that. Charging input goes into PMIC charge input and PMIC beeing a dc-dc switching converter charges the battery in a way battery is supposed too be charged.